# Eclipse pydev auto-suggestions don't work in some cases

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

My question is probably stupid and I hope somebody has succeeded in solving this issue.

Sometimes I cannot see right suggestions in auto-completion box (Eclipse 3.5.2, PyDev 1.5.7). For example:

```
import email
fp = open('my.eml', 'rb')
msg = email.message_from_file(fp)
```

`msg` now is a Message object. And functions like get_payload() works fine.

```
msg.get_payload()
```

But I don't get `get_payload()` in auto-completion list.

I think PyDev has no idea of what `msg` is, so it doesn't know what to show.

Maybe I should import something else, not only `email` module?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No question is stupid. It's only the effort of the questioner. :].

Comment: Do you say my effort is stupid? Should I be offended with this? :)

Comment: Ok then. ;) So, you know what I am talking about in the question, right? How do you manage this inconvenience?

Comment: I generally look up the API. This behaviour will improve later on with Python 3.x being more mature, but I'm trying to locate a link at the moment...

Comment: Same thing. I just use right function and forget about auto-complete at the moment.

Comment: See edited post, kishkin. `:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are, the current PyDev build hasn't gone to a point to be able to extract from a function (`message_from_file()` in your case) to know what kind of object it returns in order to provide auto-completion hinting.

See http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/forums/forum/293649/topic/3697707.

**Edit:** I believe there is interest in PyDev to support the new Python 3 function syntax, [`PEP 3107`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), which will solve some of your problems ... in the future.

Comment: So, I just need to `import __future__`? ;) Ok, we'll wait. Thank you, Xavier!

Comment: About sourceforge link. I get the thing that  PyDev cannot get specifications from compiled files. But there are also source .py files, not only .pyc. And I can actually Ctrl+click from `message_from_file` to the `Message`. But there is ambiguity at the second step: PyDev does not know where this `Parser` class came from. I think this causing the issue with autocompletion.

Comment: The real issue is from the fact that, PyDev cannot resolve what type of objects any function it's returning. It's a very complicated, possibly costly, operation. It's one of the downsides of using a dynamically typed language. Ah well. || And we basically agree.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this question quite a bit too, until I came across [this link](http://sebthom.de/140-leveraging-pydevs-auto-completion-indirectly-created-objects/). I used the second solution suggested in that link, and it works like a charm.

Basically you need to insert `assert isinstance(msg, Message)` after you get `msg` from the function call.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But could not make it work. Did all you said to do.

Comment: Can you post the code you are testing? I have seen [other posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382193/how-to-declare-variables-type-in-pydev/12409893#12409893) suggesting the same solution, and it seems to have worked for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know @type in docstring works. As in:

```
from collections import deque

def foo(a):
''' code completion sample
@type a: deque
'''
return a.popleft()  # Code completion will work here
```

I have not been able to find a way to do it inline within code (except in ways mentioned elsewhere where you simply pretend to assign the variable an instance of a type) as in:

```
from collections import deque

def foo(a):
''' code completion sample '''
if false: a = deque()
return a.popleft()  # Code completion will also work here
```

But I'm not fond of this method because it probably imposes some performance / code size penalty. I don't know / haven't checked if Python is smart enough to remove this assignment during compile time.

Thanks to [SiSoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841697/sisoie), [here's a link](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html) to page explaining possibilities.