# how to declare variable's type in pydev?

Tags: python, pydev

Suppose there's a set of class Map1,Map2,Map3,... all extended from BaseMap, and I use some reflection mechanism to get the child Map's instance. I want to dynamically get an instance of one of these classes and store it in a variable `m`, and have pydev recognize the type as BaseMap so I can use word completion on it.

I found one solution is to add the code

```
if False:
    m = BaseMap(0,0,0)
```

after assigning `m` and before using it. The line inside the if condition would never be executed, but it declares `m` is a BaseMap type object.

This may look silly, but it did work. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Related: [Autocompletion in dynamic language IDEs, specifically Python in PyDev](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3482622/95735)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pydev Code Completion for everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218778/pydev-code-completion-for-everything)  The answers on that question are more complete and up-to-date, include the sphinx `:type m: BaseMap` notation that doesn't require assertions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `assert isinstance(...)` to get autocompletion in pydev on variables where otherwise pydev would not be able to guess the correct type.

Say your code is:

```
m = getAttr(someThing, 'someAttr')
m.*no autocompletion*
```

pydev would not be able to know the type of `m` and therefore won't show the autocompletion.

Try:

```
m = getAttr(someThing, 'someAttr')
assert isinstance(m, BaseMap) # or whatever class it is
m.*pydev shows autocompletion*
```

It's somewhat *hacky*, but it will work (and also does not hurt).

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to this post: [Eclipse pydev auto-suggestions don't work in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881237/eclipse-pydev-auto-suggestions-dont-work-in-some-cases/12391684#12391684)

One good answer is already suggested (using asserts). Another solution is to use a constructors as described in [this link](http://sebthom.de/140-leveraging-pydevs-auto-completion-indirectly-created-objects/).