# PyDev in Eclipse "com/python/pydev/analysis/CtxInsensitiveImportComplProposal" code completion pop-up

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Using PyDev in Eclipse whenever I start typing code in the editor, I get a code completion suggestion of "com/python/pydev/analysis/CtxInsensitiveImportComplProposal". It doesn't matter what I'm typing, I get the same suggestion. If I turn off code completion, it goes away, but I'd like for it to work right. Any way to get rid of this?

Comment: Did you try this? May be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/2881300/2691625

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyDev 5.3 requires Eclipse 4.6 (Neon)... So, if you upgrade your Eclipse installation it should work.

If you can't upgrade,  please keep using an older version of PyDev too.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading Eclipse fixed the problem. Funny, when you use their installer and scroll down the list to the "Standard" installation instead of using the Java environment at the top of the list, you don't get the newest version.

Comment: I am not able to install the latest version of Eclipse (I get "The download.eclipse.org page isn’t working"). How do I install an older version of PyDev? I can only install the latest version from http://pydev.org/updates

Comment: Update sites for older PyDev versions can be seen at: http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/ another choice (although commercial) is getting LiClipse, which comes with PyDev and a java vm bulitin: http://www.liclipse.com